# ModuleNotFoundError despite package installation

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

For an unknown reason, some functions of the Python package `GeoPandas` were not working on my PC any more. I therefore deinstalled and reinstalled Anaconda and also installed the Python package `GeoPandas` via `conda create -n geo-env -c conda-forge geopandas` which is now check-marked as *installed* in the Anaconda package overview.

[image]

However, when I run `import geopandas` in Spyder I receive the following error:

```
runfile('untitled0.py', wdir='/Downloads')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "untitled0.py", line 1, in <module>
    import geopandas

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopandas'
```

Does anyone have an idea what I can do? I made sure I am running the correct Anaconda environment.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with Spyder and haven't used Anaconda much, but I got curious. The first thing is that you want to install the Spyder-kernel as described [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder) in your `geo-env` environment (you might already have done that). Great, all done, you load up Spyder, change your runtime to the correct python in your environment and... It doesn't work.

From my testing, Spyder is not very dynamic, so I had to restart Spyder once I had set it up to the correct environment. On restart, you will notice that the iPython window attempts to load the kernel and then it will work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't know what exactly did the job but the combination of a restart (pretty sure I did that before) and the installation of the Kernel into the new environment solved my problem. Thank you!!